# Group by color, sum by b, then a/b and make a new column for the new calculation. My code below shows output for the new calculation column is wrong

Tags: python, pandas

```
color  a    b
blue   100  25
blue   200  10
blue   450  50
red    60   2
red    75   3
red    80   4
orange 125  5
orange 90   9
orange 36   4
```

I've tried

```
def x():

    getcal=df['a']/df['b']
    df["new calculation"]=getcal 
    trythis=df[["color", "a", "b", "new calculation"]]
    final = trythis.groupby(by = "color").sum().sort_values(by="b")
    print(final)

x()
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
df = (df.groupby('color', as_index=False)['a','b']
        .sum()
        .assign(calculation=lambda x: x.a / x.b)
        .sort_values(by="b"))
print (df)
    color    a   b  calculation
2     red  215   9    23.888889
1  orange  251  18    13.944444
0    blue  750  85     8.823529
```